# Combining django Managers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have two django managers

### Vote manager

```
class VoteManager(model.Manager):

    def all_with_vote_info(self):
        qs = super(VoteManager, self).get_query_set()
        qs = qs.annotate(score=Sum('votes__score', distinct=True))
        return qs

    ....
```

### Soft Delete manager

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):

    def all_active(self):
        qs = super(SoftDeleteManager, self).get_query_set()
        qs = qs.filter(time_deleted=None)
        return qs

    ....
```

How can I chain queryset results from `VoteManager.all_with_vote_info`, `SoftDeleteManager.all_active`, and any arbitrary number of manager methods?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: `PassThroughManager`

https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#passthroughmanager

**Update:**

`PassThroughManager` has been deprecated, use Django’s built-in `QuerySet.as_manager()` and/or `Manager.from_queryset()` utilities instead.

Comment: Could we get some examples of how we might combine two third party managers/query set using the as_manager from from_queryset methods?

Answer (score 0):

Using this method PolymorphicQuerySet methods will all be available, then we can register additional methods from the TimeseriesQueryset

```
class UserPartQuerySet(PolymorphicQuerySet, TimeSeriesQuerySet):


    def prefetch_latest(self, *related_names):
        return TimeSeriesQuerySet.prefetch_latest(self, *related_names)

    def filter_outdated(self, *related_names):
        return TimeSeriesQuerySet.filter_outdated(self, *related_names)

    def update_timeseries(self, related_name, collector, force=False):
        return TimeSeriesQuerySet.update_timeseries(
                self,
                related_name,
                collector,
                force=False
        )
```

Comment: why even override the methods?